# Using -setValue:forKey: vs "object.var = ..."

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, key-value-observing, key-value-coding

The difference between these two lines of code is that the second is KVO compliant and the first isn't?

```
[person setValue:tempPerson.name forKey:@"name"];
person.name = tempPerson.name;
```

The reason I'm asking is because I need to update 60 attributes on over 500 objects, I don't want KVO notifications for more than a handful of attributes.

I'm using NSFecthedResultsController for my UITableView and I don't want to trigger excessive setNeedDisplay on the cells.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no difference between the two lines as far as Key-Value Observing is concerned. Both trigger KVO notifications by default. You can override this behavior, though. From Apples' KVO Programming Guide:

> You can control automatic observer notifications for properties of your subclass by implementing the class method `automaticallyNotifiesObserversForKey:`. Subclasses can test the key passed as the parameter and return YES if automatic notification should be enabled, NO if it should be disabled.

Comment: Thanks, so it's just a different style and no benefit to using either approach?

Comment: The first line executes slower and is harder to read, so I see no benefit in using it unless you have to (that is, the name of the property is a variable and not known at compile time).